# How to access data created through context in getServerSideProps outside of that function (for CRA to Nextjs migration)

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript, next.js, server-side-rendering

I am using Create react app right now for a react application and trying to migrate to Nextjs.
Accessing url date like host, protocol and query params have become a big problem.

Finally Realized that I need to access them through the context prop in getServerSideProps function, I am returning them as props to my component but I dont want to pass down as props to a child components function that is many levels down. How can I access this url info elsewhere in a very deep child components functions.

This is the function from CRA. I obviously cant use window.location.hostname on the server side, so I am looking for a different implementation.

```
if (window !== undefined) {
    const host = window.location.hostname;
    if (host.includes('dev.')) {
        env = 'DEV';
    } else if (host.includes('int.')) {
        env = 'INT';
    } else if (host.includes('localhost') || host.includes('127.0.0.1')) {
        env = 'LOCAL';
    }
}
```

Coming to nextjs work, I wrote the gerServerSideProps function to fetch these details.

```
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps<{requestUrlData: programServerSideProps}> = async (context: any) => {
const requestUrlData = await absoluteUrl(context.req);
return { props : {requestUrlData} }
```

}

how do I access this requestUrlData data in that function without passing down as props through many child components?

Answer (score 0):

You can access full `router` object using next's build-in [`useRouter`](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/functions/use-router) hook.

And to get your current domain you should set it to env variables with prefix [`NEXT_PUBLIC_`](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/environment-variables#bundling-environment-variables-for-the-browser) (`NEXT_PUBLIC_DOMAIN`) in both your dev and prod environments. This prexix allows you to access variables from the browser with `process.env['NEXT_PUBLIC_DOMAIN']`